# How to get a unique value from a list in python

Tags: python

Imagine I have this list:

```
list = ['a','a','b','a']
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
print(unique(list))
```

to retrieve the unique item(s), so python will output `b`. How could I do this?

Comment: do you mean sets? Or do you mean you only want to print a certain element from the list?

Comment: Hint: The `count()` method of lists.

Comment: @ItsFragilis They have a list and they want to return only the elements that appear once.

Comment: Unrelated, don't use the name `list` for a variable name in Python, as it overrides a built-in name (the list constructor). Same for `dict`, `sum`, and more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Count the items, keep only those which have a count of 1:

```
>>> data = ['a','a','b','a']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [k for k,v in Counter(data).items() if v == 1]
['b']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using set() property of Python, we can easily check for the unique values. Insert the values of the list in a set. Set only stores a value once even if it is inserted more then once. After inserting all the values in the set by list_set=set(list1), convert this set to a list to print it.

for more ways check : [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-unique-values-list/#:~:text=Using%20set()%20property%20of,a%20list%20to%20print%20it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-unique-values-list/#:%7E:text=Using%20set()%20property%20of,a%20list%20to%20print%20it).

Example to make a unique function :

```
# Python program to check if two
# to get unique values from list
# using set

# function to get unique values
def unique(list1):
 
    # insert the list to the set
    list_set = set(list1)
    # convert the set to the list
    unique_list = (list(list_set))
    for x in unique_list:
        print x,
 

# driver code
list1 = [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 40]
print("the unique values from 1st list is")
unique(list1)


list2 =[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5]
print("\nthe unique values from 2nd list is")
unique(list2)
```

output should be:
the unique values from 1st list is
40 10 20 30
the unique values from 2nd list is
1 2 3 4 5

You can also use numpy.unique example:

`
#Ppython program to check if two
# to get unique values from list
# using numpy.unique
import numpy as np

```
# function to get unique values
def unique(list1):
    x = np.array(list1)
    print(np.unique(x))
 

# driver code
list1 = [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 40]
print("the unique values from 1st list is")
unique(list1)


list2 =[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5]
print("\nthe unique values from 2nd list is")
unique(list2)
```

`
output should be :
the unique values from 1st list is
[10 20 30 40]

the unique values from 2nd list is
[1 2 3 4 5]

Fore more please check "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-unique-values-list/#:~:text=Using%20set()%20property%20of,a%20list%20to%20print%20it."

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this, e.g.:

```py
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['a','a','b','a']

counts = Counter(my_list)

for element, count in counts.items():
    if count == 1:
        print(element)
```

would print `b` and nothing else in this case.

Or, if you'd like to store the result in a list:

```py
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['a','a','b','a']

counts = Counter(my_list)

unique_elements = [element for element, count in counts.items() if count == 1]
```

`unique_elements` is `['b']` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Most straight forward way, use a `dict` of counters.

```
a = ['a','a','b','a']

counts = {}
for element in a:
    counts[element] = counts.get(element, 0) + 1

for element in a:
    if counts[element] == 1:
        print(element)
```

out:

```
b
```

Comment: Those conditions can be replaced with : `counts[element] = counts.get(element, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I will forever use it that way. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

1. Count the appearance of an element in the list, and store it in a dictionary
2. From the dictionary, check which elements has only one appearance
3. Store the unique (one appearance) elements in a list
4. Print the list

You can try this:

```
my_list = ['a','a','b','a']
my_dict = {}
only_one = []

#Step 1
for element in my_list:
  if element not in my_dict:
    my_dict[element] = 1
  else:
    my_dict[element] += 1

#Step 2 and Step 3
for key, value in my_dict.items():
  if value == 1:
    only_one.append(key)

#Step 4
for unique in only_one:
  print(unique)
```

Output:

```
b
```

In case you are wondering what other variables contain:

```
my_dict = {'a': 3, 'b': 1}
only_one = ['b']
```